# converting between List types, java

Tags: java, list

So I am writing a method that returns `List<V>`. However, the list that I've made in the method is `List<Vertex<V>>`. I was wondering if there's some way to convert `List<Vertex<V>>` to `List<V>` to match the return type other than just removing the "Vertex" part. Thanks!

Comment: You could write custom code to getV() from Vertex then add V to different List<V> but you can not cast it unless Vertex<V> extends V which in your case I don't think it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using java 8 there's an easy way to map a collection to a different type of collections simple write:

```
list.stream().map(vertex -> vertex.get()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`vertex.get()` should be any code that takes a `Vertex<V>` and converts it to `V`.

Comment: You can also do `map(Vertex::get)` instead of `map(vertex -> vertex.get())`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no, you can't solve this with "casting" alone.
`V` is not the same as `Vertex<V>` so you need a way to extract the `V` object from each of your `Vertex<V>` objects.